# Algorithm to beat bots moving towards prizes predictably

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

For this game, there is a 10x10 board and a few different prizes with values from 1 to 9, there are a few simple bots playing where one always goes after the closest prize, and another always goes for the prize with the greatest number of points assigned to it. Bots and prizes are placed randomly on the board. The task is to create another simple AI which always collects the highest number of points total and wins the game.

How would I go about picking between prize points and prize distance which would allow this new AI to always win the game? I was thinking I would favor closer prizes, but go towards a larger prize if it is 2 larger than the closest one, however this doesn't always win.

The bots do not know where the bots are and if one bot moves 8 spaces for one prize another can move 8 spaces and collect multiple prizes during that time. All the bots move at once and can move diagonally. The game ends once there is no more prizes on the board.

Comment: This question is too vague and can be answered too broadly. This is discouraged in SO.

Comment: Please give more details about your game rules. For example, if bot A goes for a far away prize with 8 steps, do that mean bot B can get 2 prizes with 4 steps each? Besides, since prize and bots are randomly placed, how can one bot always win? Imagine 2 bots are using your "always-win-algorithm", there must be a winner and a loser(except draw occationally).

Comment: Please edit your question (instead of replying in a comment) and answer the following:  Do all the bots move at the same time?  Does it take one unit of time to move from one cell to another?  Can a bot move to any of the squarely adjacent 4 cells, or to diagonally adjacent also?  Can your bot get the information about where the other two bots are, and which is which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee a win.  If bots/prizes are placed randomly, there are surely random placements that will put you too far away from prizes before the other bots get them.

Since you know the exact behavior of the other bots, you can model all future moves they will make for a given board.  You can then enumerate all possible moves as a tree, and board states, then look at the leaves and find the one that gives you a winning score.  In other words, each branch is a move you make, and the node represents the board state including the move that the other bots will make.  Also, this won't be a binary tree, each node will branch based on the directions you could move that turn.  You will completely build this tree before you make a single actual move, so that essentially you will have the outcome of the game predicted once you choose the optimum path.  This is possible only because the other bots move in a predictable manner.

Also as you move, you can add checks to ensure the other bots are moving as you predicted, just as a debugging feature.  Depending on how the system operates, they may see your move before they decide their move, depending on if everyone moves simultaneously, or one at a time.  Either way it can be done, you just have to make sure your model of how they move is accurate.

Note that there might be other leaves where you have a larger score but lose because one of the other bots dominated the other.  I.e. (you:12, a:1, b:17) vs. (you:11, a:10, b:9)

The paths that will probably succeed the most are the ones that exploit the behavior of the other bots, for example, grabbing the highest prize when it is closer to you, causing the greedy bot to loose moves going towards it.  And also sidetracking for prizes on the way if you have enough moves to do so.  You won't have to code for this behavior though, because when you create the tree and find the optimum series of moves, you it will occur implicitly.

Comment: It sounds like, aside from who gets the prize first, the bots don't actually affect each other.  So rather than enumerating every possible move you only need to enumerate the different choices of which prize to go for next.  This will *drastically* reduce the size of the search-tree - there's only 9! = 362880 different outcomes to examine, which can be cut down even further by pruning the search-space (stop searching a sub-tree when you are guaranteed to have won or lost)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If you don't consider the other bots moves then you will plan a course that will involve moving to squares where there once was a prize but is snatched up by another bot before you.  The fact that they move in a predictable manner I think is the key to winning.  You could still reduce the search tree by stopping at subtrees where you are in an unwinnable position, I.e. your the diff between you and highest scorer is greater than amount of prizes left on the board.

Comment: The search tree would have to be recreated and analyzed after every single move to take into account prizes that are picked up by other bots. Instead of creating the whole tree every time, I'm thinking it would be better to only generate a partial tree to take this into account.

Comment: @fotg & Aaron: There is no need to consider the exact moves *(unless the bots can, say, run into each other; the question does not specify)*.  Since you know the exact time that each of the other bots will reach that square, and you know how long it will take for your bot to reach that square, you can simply check if he'll make it in time, and if not, prune that subtree.  That would just reduce your search-space even more.

Comment: @fotg You've already selected the optimum path based on the moves of the other bots.  You won't need to regenerate the tree because the path you selected is based on those very moves being predictable.  I see though that you updated the question and say you don't know starting location of other bots.  If you can see prizes disappear, then you will know where the other bots are, and can build an accurate tree from that point going forward.  This will be quick for the closest bot, and easy to predict for the greedy bot.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft What if that square is at one corner, but all the other prizes are near the other corner?  You go for the highest scoring prize just so you can beat the greedy bot to it, while the closest-bot behavior is gobbling up all the others and wins.  If you have a completely predictable oppononent then you should take advantage of it.

Comment: @AaronLS: I think you're not understanding my suggestion.  We are both recommending brute-forcing every possible solution, but I am saying it's only necessary to brute-force the various permutations of prize-orders, not every individual move.  I am not giving a recommendation for any particular heuristic for the bot *(heuristics are not necessary since the search-space is so small)*.  So in your example above, moving to the corner-prize first would be **considered**, but so would moving to every other prize first.  In the end, you will have the guaranteed best solution.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Oh I see, I thought you were advocating for something that just considered only the next move. I agree this could be optimized in terms of processing/memory and get the same optimum results. It is pointless to build part of the tree where your moves are just leading to an empty square, or to have a node for every single move when you could really just model the moves up to the next prize grab and make that a node, and only could code it to predict moves towards grabable prizes.  Depends on if this is throw away code or not.